# XML parsing in Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, css-selectors

I have an XML file which has four `<resutGroups>` tag:

```
<resultGroups>
  <subGroups>
    <name> </name>
  </subGroups>
  <name> </name>
</resultGroups>
```

each `<resultGroup>` has several `<subGroups>` and each `<subGroups>` has `<name>` tag.

I want to select only the name tag of `<resultGroups>` only

```
$(xml).find("resultGroups").each(function() {
  alert( $(this).find("name").text() ); 
}
```

When I use the above code it returns all the names inside the `<resultgroups>` and `<subGroups>`.

How can I select only one `<name>` which is in the `<resultGroups>` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

```
var xml = $(xml);
$('resultGroups > name', xml).each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

This uses the [direct descendant](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/child#parentchild) selector. You could also use [`children`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children), which does the same thing:

```
$('resultGroups', xml).children('name').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```