# Duplicate Jquery XML parsing

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Struggling to figure this out.

I've got an XML file that I call with ajax, then I need to set the element text as variables.

Two of the elements have the same name, and I don't know how to get them separately:

```
<myElement>

    <Country>
       <Id>1</Id>
       <CountryCode>UK</CountryCode>
       **<Name>United Kingdom</Name>**
    </Country>

    <County>
       <Id>7</Id>
       **<Name>West Midlands</Name>**
    </County>

</myElement>
```

This is how I currently get them:

```
    $(results).find("myElement").each(function (i, item) {
        var countryName = $(this).find('Name').text();
        var countyName = **$(this).find(' ???? ').text();** 

    });
```

Not come across this before, but the XML file ISN'T mine so I can't just rename the elements.

Comment: Are you still experiencing any difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your county is outside of your country tag, so therefore you'd have to do something like this for that line.

```
$('County', results).children('Name').each(function(){
  countyName = $(this).text();
});
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980413/xml-parsing-in-jquery) further expands upon the above code, and describes it a bit more fully.

Comment: ^^
Sorry I missed the outer element wrap, I've included that now!

Answer (score 0):

I did similar to the above, when there was a duplicate I did this:

```
$('Country > Name', results).each(function () {
    countryName = $(this).text();
});
```

Where there wasn't I did this:

```
    mainText = $(this).find('MainText').text();
```